# What is the best way to save an image inside an User object?

Tags: android, image, class, listview, imageview

I don't have any code. I can add in my class an ImageView or a Bitmap, or something else?

1. They have a form to fill with their datas (name, email, etc) and a photo taken from gallery. At the moment I took the photo from the gallery and it is showing inside the Image View of the form.
2. When I press save, an user object is created from the Edit Texts and the ImageView.
3. It is saved inside an ArrayList.
4. The array is listed inside a listView in another activity.

The single problem I have is with the Image because I don't know how to save it or what type should I use in the class.

Answer (score 1):

you may achieve your goal by selecting any one of the following

1. Choose Uri as data type into your model and update model after onActivityResult you can get uri from data of onActivityResult param
2. Create file object from data and store getAbsolutePath()
3. Create Bitmap and you can store bytes in your database.

Comment: And if I want to move a Uri to another, should I go uri1=uri2?

Comment: if you want to move it to next screen then intent will handle Uri as well, no need other variable and if you're in the same class it depends on scenario. but 2 variable having same data type in same context is not recommended